How to Properly Clear All Connections for a Google Street View Photo Using Google Street View Publish API and Python?
I am trying to clear all connections for a Google Street View photo using the google.streetview.publish_v1 Python client library. However, I am encountering issues where the connections are not being cleared as expected. Here is my current code:
from google.streetview.publish_v1 import StreetViewPublishServiceClient
from google.streetview.publish_v1 import types, enums
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
import os
import pickle


def authenticate():
    client_secrets_file = 'path_to_my_client_secrets_file.json' 
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/streetviewpublish']
    credentials = None

    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            credentials = pickle.load(token)

    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file, scopes)
            credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(credentials, token)

    return credentials


def initialize_streetview_publish_api():
    credentials = authenticate()
    client = StreetViewPublishServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
    return client


def clear_connections(client, photo_id):
    try:
        # Specify the view parameter
        photo = client.get_photo(photo_id=photo_id, view=enums.PhotoView.INCLUDE_DOWNLOAD_URL)
        print(f"Original connections for {photo_id}: {photo.connections}")

        # Clear connections
        photo.connections.clear()
        response = client.update_photo(photo=photo, update_mask=types.FieldMask(paths=['connections']))
        print(f"Cleared connections for {photo_id}: {response.connections}")

        # Verify that the connections have been cleared
        updated_photo = client.get_photo(photo_id=photo_id, view=enums.PhotoView.INCLUDE_DOWNLOAD_URL)
        print(f"Connections after clearing for {photo_id}: {updated_photo.connections}")

        if not updated_photo.connections:
            print(f"Successfully cleared all connections for {photo_id}.")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to clear all connections for {photo_id}.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error clearing connections for {photo_id}: {e}")


def main():
    streetview_client = initialize_streetview_publish_api()

    photo_id_to_update = 'my_photo_id'  # Change this to a placeholder

    clear_connections(streetview_client, photo_id_to_update)
    print(f"Deleted all connections for photo {photo_id_to_update}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The script runs without errors, but the connections are not actually cleared. Here is the output I get:
Original connections for my_photo_id: [target {
  id: "some_target_id"
}
, target {
  id: "another_target_id"
}
]
Cleared connections for my_photo_id: []
Connections after clearing for my_photo_id: [target {
  id: "some_target_id"
}
, target {
  id: "another_target_id"
}
]
Failed to clear all connections for my_photo_id.
Deleted all connections for photo my_photo_id

Process finished with exit code 0

How can I correctly clear all connections for a Street View photo? Is there something wrong with my approach or a missing step in my code?

I made it in this way:
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import os
import pickle
import json
import time


def authenticate():
    # Path to the client_secret.json file
    client_secrets_file = 'path_to_my_client_secrets_file.json'
    # Path where the credential pickle file will be stored
    credentials_pickle_file = 'path_to_my_credentials.pickle'
    # Scopes required for the Street View Publish API
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/streetviewpublish']

    credentials = None
    # Load credentials from the pickle file if it exists
    if os.path.exists(credentials_pickle_file):
        with open(credentials_pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            credentials = pickle.load(token)

    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        try:
            if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
                credentials.refresh(Request())
            else:
                raise Exception("Invalid credentials, initiating new login flow.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            # Remove the invalid credentials file
            if os.path.exists(credentials_pickle_file):
                os.remove(credentials_pickle_file)
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file, scopes)
            credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open(credentials_pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(credentials, token)

    return credentials


def initialize_streetview_publish_api():
    credentials = authenticate()
    service = build('streetviewpublish', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    return service


def get_photo(service, photo_id):
    try:
        photo = service.photo().get(photoId=photo_id, view='INCLUDE_DOWNLOAD_URL').execute()
        return photo
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting photo: {e}")
        return None


def clear_connections(service, photo_id):
    photo_body = {
        "photoId": {
            "id": photo_id
        },
        "connections": []
    }
    update_body = {
        "updatePhotoRequests": [
            {
                "updateMask": "connections",
                "photo": photo_body
            }
        ]
    }
    try:
        response = service.photos().batchUpdate(body=update_body).execute()
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error clearing connections: {e}")
        return None


def main():
    photo_id_to_update = 'my_photo_id'
    streetview_service = initialize_streetview_publish_api()

    # Get current photo metadata
    photo_metadata = get_photo(streetview_service, photo_id_to_update)
    if photo_metadata is None:
        print("Failed to retrieve photo metadata")
        return
    print(f"Original connections for {photo_id_to_update}: {photo_metadata.get('connections', [])}")

    # Clear connections
    update_response = clear_connections(streetview_service, photo_id_to_update)
    if update_response is None:
        print("Failed to update photo connections")
        return
    print(f"Update Response: {json.dumps(update_response, indent=2)}")

    # Wait for some time to ensure the changes are reflected
    time.sleep(10)

    # Verify that connections are cleared
    updated_metadata = get_photo(streetview_service, photo_id_to_update)
    if updated_metadata is None:
        print("Failed to retrieve updated photo metadata")
        return
    print(f"Connections after clearing for {photo_id_to_update}: {updated_metadata.get('connections', [])}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Update:
The same code that worked yesterday is not working today. It might be a propagation issue.
